# How I can use sessions in my code using asp.net vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

I want to make sessions, but i don't know from where I can start. I logged in myself, but without using session and i have to make sessions. Below is my code which I have done so far.

```
Protected Sub btnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click

    If txt_username.Text = "" Or txt_password.Text = "" Then
        error_usr_invalid.Visible = False
        If txt_username.Text = "" Then
            error_usr_blank.Visible = True
        ElseIf txt_username.Text <> "" Then
            error_usr_blank.Visible = False
        End If
        If txt_password.Text = "" Then
            error_pwd_blank.Visible = True
        ElseIf txt_username.Text <> "" Then
            error_pwd_blank.Visible = False
        End If
    ElseIf txt_username.Text <> "" And txt_password.Text <> "" Then
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from users where username = '" + txt_username.Text + "' and Password = '" + txt_password.Text + "'", con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txt_username.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txt_password.Text)
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        da.Fill(dt)
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            error_usr_invalid.Visible = False
            error_usr_blank.Visible = False
            error_pwd_blank.Visible = False

            Response.Redirect("main.aspx")
        Else
            error_usr_invalid.Visible = True
            error_usr_blank.Visible = False
            error_pwd_blank.Visible = False
        End If
    End If
```

Please help me out by suggesting your ideas in this code.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about session here : [ASP.NET Session State Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

Now, there is just few examples :

Add value to session : `Session.Add("username", txt_username.Text)`

Get value from session : `Dim username As String = Session("username")`

For example : You can store username into `Session("username")` and use it on some other page (for example in Your `main.aspx`) until You remove it.

One more example :

*Default.aspx*

```
Protected Sub btnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
  Session.Add("username", txt_username.Text)
  Response.Redirect("main.aspx")
End Sub
```

And in *main.aspx* :

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  Label1.Text = Session("username")
End Sub
```

Session can be used for storing arrays, and other type of datas. For example :

```
Session.Add("list", List(Of String))
Session("list").Add("record #1")
Session("list").Add("record #2")
Session("list").Add("record #3")
```

And then use it somewhere else :

```
For x = 0 to Session("list").Count - 1
  Label1.Text = Session("list")(x) + ", "
Next
```

Remove session : `Session.Remove("username")` (this session item will be removed)

When You finished with Your work (for example You log out), You can remove, clear, abandon session.

`Session.RemoveAll() : Session.Clear() : Session.Abandon()`

You can store some data into session and use it anywhere in Your web app.

btw. in Your code, little better approach will be :

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString)
If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then con.Close()
con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ToString
con.Open()
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from users where username = @username and Password = @password;", con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txt_username.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txt_password.Text)
Dim tds As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
Session.Add("isexist", tds.HasRows)   'there is example how to store result into session (in this case result value will be True or False)
tds.Close(): cmd.Dispose(): con.Close()  'avoid connection stay opened
If Session("isexist") = True Then
  'user successful log in, session("isexist") is True
  Session.Remove("isexist")
  Response.Redirect("main.aspx")
Else
  'username or password doesn't exist in database, session("isexist") is False
  Session.Remove("isexist") 
 'do what You want
End If
```

Of course, You have to pay attention for `session` `timeout`.... You can read more by provided link on the start of this post.

Answer (score 0):

Simple as this...

```
    Session("Username") = txt_username.Text
```

After that, you can get the value of the `session` on every page.